# Check TreeView ScrollBar Visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, scrollbar

How can i check if the Vertical ScrollBar in a TreeView is Visible?

Comment: add more details, what have you tried, what is you original form,code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must do some p/invoke to get the style of TreeView.

```
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    bool VScrollVisible()
    {
        int style = GetWindowLong(myTreeView.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
        return  ((style & WS_VSCROLL) != 0);
    }
```

Comment: note: GetWindowLong is different for 32bit vs 64bit execution. See here for solution to this: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowLong